# Complex numbers - conditions for existence of a solution

Tags: complex-numbers

here is an interesting problem which I am not able to solve. We can freely choose $z_1$, $z_2$ and $z_3$ are all complex numbers (at most one of them can be a real number). **What conditions for numbers $z_1$, $z_2$ and $z_3$ or $z$ must be done (stated) if the equation $ |z-z_1|+|z-z_2|=|z_3| $ must have a solution?**

Note: $z$ means $z=x+i.y$.

$z_1$, $z_2$ and $z_3$ are any complex numbers (for example $i$, $2+i$,$1-i$ etc.) 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ |z-z_1|+|z-z_2|=|z_3| $ is ellipse with foci at $z_1,z_2$ with major axis$=|z_3|$ if $|z_1-z_2|<|z_3|.$